# cant enter the phpmyadmin docker

Tags: phpmyadmin, docker

I'm using docker and want to dockerize a drupal.
I create container with drupal , mysql , phpmyadmin and linked all at one port. The question is that I can not enter the phpmyadmin.
I created phpmyadmin container with this

```
docker run -d --link dtbase  -e MYSQL_USERNAME=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123  --name phpmyadminnew -p 80 corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
```

cant enter with this pass and username.

Answer (score 2):

From https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin/dockerfile/

Try to login to phpmyadmin using:

Login: `pma`

Password: `password`

Or set your own with variables:

```
-e PMA_USERNAME=root -e PMA_PASSWORD=123
```